# STAThead on a DLL for using with Task/BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, com, .net-4.0, backgroundworker, task

Good morning,

I made a simple dll in which I use a WebBrowser control to do some simple tasks. Now I want to use its methods from the main UI in a separate Task or a BackgroundWorker. The problem is that whenever I use the methods I get the "no `STAThread`" exception... How can I get around this? Of course, in the dll there is no `Main()` method and I can't either add the `STAThread` attribute to the constructor.

Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 The "Good morning" part is slightly amusing, given that it's 12:59 AM in my time zone here. :)

Comment: Please post full exception details. And also try to mark your main method with `[STAThread]` attribute.

Comment: @decyclone: Changing the Main method will only make the UI thread an STAThread (which it should be anyway).

Comment: @Jon: I guess you are right. I remember now I had to create a new thread with STA apartment state for similar issue on my Win Forms application.

Comment: @rene: No, there can be multiple UI threads in one process, but only one UI thread for a given *window*. You could have one thread showing an animated splash screen which another UI thread builds the main UI, for example.

Comment: @rene - I'm not sure that's correct. I've certainly built demo applications in the past that called Application.Run from multiple threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to get code running in a new STA thread you should create a new thread and explicitly force it to be an STAThread using [`Thread.SetApartmentState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx) before starting it. You'll then need to use `Control.BeginInvoke` to marshal calls back to the UI thread - you don't want to use `BackgroundWorker` or `Task`, as those will use a threadpool thread.

On the other hand, it's not clear whether that will help in this case - if you're using a `WebBrowserControl` you'll probably need a message loop running etc.

It's not really clear what you mean by "use its methods from the main UI". Is this WebBrowserControl *part* of the UI which is running in the normal UI thread? If so, you'll need to marshal *to* that thread from the other thread (e.g. using `Control.BeginInvoke`) - and the other thread doesn't need to be an STA thread for that to happen.

Comment: The WebBrowser is not meant to be visible, so it is not part of the UI thread. I only use it to access sites in the background and do tasks with it.

Comment: @Miguel: Just because it's not visible doesn't mean it won't need all the normal facilities available to something running on a UI thread. I strongly suspect you'll need to have it belonging to a window, created on a UI thread. Just make it invisible.

Comment: @Miguel, if you're only using the WebBrowser control "in the background", does that mean you're just using it to make WebRequests but not render the output?  You should look at System.Web.HttpWebRequest; it might suit your needs better.